# ¿Como pasar mas de un argumento a una funcion desde la platilla Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, djangorestframework

Normalmente uso la forma que se muestra en la documentación en mi caso seria asi

> {% url 'estudiante:realizar_temario' temario.pk  %}

y asi funciona bien, el problema está en que quiero pasarle ademas de temario.pk la hora actual en que se llama la función si usó "," para separar da error y dejando espacio igual, para obtener la hora estoy usando la etiqueta "now", no se si sea ese el problema, agradezco cualquier aporte.

Comment: simplemente tienes que añadirle el segundo argumento a la url igual que añades el primero. Ejemplo: `{% url 'estudiante:realizar_temario' temario.pk temario.segunda_pk %}`. Por otra parte también debes configurar tu url y tu función para que acepten 2 argumentos.

Comment: La forma en la que lo haces (con el espacio) es la correcta, el problema es que quieres pasar un `tag` como parámetro, creo que debes replantearte que datos pasar por url, ya que si quieres la hora actual, bastaría con obtenerla en la vista sin necesidad de pasarlo por ulr. Ahora, donde sí o sí necesites pasarla por ahí, siempre puedes crear una variable y pasarla al template con la hora, al crear la variable y pasarla, siempre y cuando sea un tipo nativo como `string` o `int` podrás pasarla por la url

Comment: Germán Alzate entiendo lo q me dices de la hora pero el problema es q la función q llamo es recursiva y la llamo varias veces hasta q termine lo q deceo tomar es la hora de la primera llamda, no se me ocurrió otra forma q usar TAG y volver a pasarle cuando la volviera a llamar para q no se modificará

Comment: revisa esto espero te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat